# Prevent UITapGestureRecognizer on Subview

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitapgesturerecognizer

I don't want `closeShareView` being called when the user taps on `contentView`, only on `modalView`, how can I do that?

```
UIWindow* mainWindow = (((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).window);

// Modal view
UIView *modalView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
modalView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.8f];

// Content view (goes inside modalView)
UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(modalView.center.x, modalView.center.y, 220, 220)];
[modalView addSubview:contentView];
[mainWindow addSubview:modalView];

// Tap gesture (added to modalView)
UITapGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(closeShareView:)];
gr.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[modalView addGestureRecognizer:gr];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want something like a "click outside the content view to dismiss the modal" kind of deal?

Instead of adding the tap gesture to the entire modal view, have a background view that handles that, and the content view will naturally intercept all taps (if it has user interaction enabled), so you basically don't have to do any coding.

```
UIWindow* mainWindow = (((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).window);

// Modal view
UIView *modalView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

// Background tap view
UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:modalView.bounds];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.8];
[modalView addSubview:backgroundView];

// Content view (goes inside modalView)
UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(modalView.center.x, modalView.center.y, 220, 220)];
[modalView addSubview:contentView];
[mainWindow addSubview:modalView];

// Tap gesture (added to backgroundView)
UITapGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(closeShareView:)];
gr.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[backgroundView addGestureRecognizer:gr];
```

Comment: The modal view is that background view. The taps still get recognized by the subview even if user interaction is enabled.

Comment: The modal view is not just the background view, it's the parent view, and if you add a gesture recognizer to the parent view, it will handle it, of course it won't work

So, you can add another `UIView` (or `UIControl` if you're feeling super lazy) on `modalView`, but behind `contentView` and that will take care of that.

Comment: I literally just copy+pasted the code in a new project, and worked (which also surprised me :D ).

Comment: Shifting the UIGestureRecognizer to the background view works beautifully. Nice answer.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, adhere to the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol in your header file.

*Set the delegate*  of the `UIGestureRecognizer` to `self`.

Then set the *tag* of your subview e.g. to 100 (but you should use a constant).

Then use something like:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint point = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];
    UIView *viewTouched = [self.view hitTest:point withEvent:nil];
    if (viewTouched.tag == 100) {
        // Don't BEGIN the gestureRecognizer
        return NO;
    } else {
        // Do BEGIN the gestureRecognizer
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just checking to see if the touched view is self, else it's a subview and the gesture shouldn't begin:

```
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    let point = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.view)
    if let viewTouched = self.view.hitTest(point, withEvent: nil) where viewTouched != self.view {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    let point = sender.location(in: subview)
    if !(tapView.frame.contains(point)) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Here, tapview is the view on which the tap gesture is added and subview is it's subview

Comment: Didn't work for taps below the subview - they were not recognized as a background taps.

Answer (score 0):

I have a `backgroundView` and a `tableView` above it:

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(backgroundTapped))
tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
backgroundView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)



// MARK: - UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

extension PhoneListViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        let point = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.tableView)
        return !self.tableView.point(inside: point, with: nil)
    }
}
```